# Flask keeping checkboxes after page regresh

Tags: flask, post, checkbox, get, webserver

I have this piece of code of a flask template

```
<div class="rows">
     <h3>In oven</h3>
     {% for checkbox in checkboxes: %}
     <li><input type="checkbox"></li>
     {% endfor %}
</div>
```

I tried using java script but after refresh the checkboxes resets even if I checked it before. I want to checked it and after refreshing the page the check to stay. Any ideas how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store somewhere the value of the checkbox to set it when loading the page again.

- Local storage
- Flask session
- Database
- Ajax query
- With a form

This value has to be something that can be evaluated as true/false.

After retrieving the value you need to evaluate for add or not the checked property in the input.

In this example, I'm using a variable on the view.

```
#app.py
@app.route("/")
def sample():
    your_variable=True
    return render_template('index.html', your_variable=your_variable)

#index.html
<div class="rows">
     <h3>In oven</h3>
     {% for checkbox in checkboxes: %}
     <li><input type="checkbox" {{'checked="checked"' if your_variable else ""}}></li>
     {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Of course, with a more complete question this can be more specific

Comment: how can I use local storage to store it and how loud the code look like for the storing(is it a seperate file that needs to be put in the templates? )

Comment: @vvg if you want, you can ask that in a new question and tag me in the comment then I can help you. Because you can't ask two different element on the same question